# Unity5 collab commit/publish error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am often getting the below error while trying to publish changes to Unity collab repository.

I have changed files in my local repository, When I try to publish, collab throwing this error and saying that you are up to date!. But my changes are not getting sync

**Unity Version : 5.4.1p2**

> Error: Cannot submit change to server

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: its unity server error